# Are Quines played-out?

Tags: discussion

I'll confess off the bat that I have not investigated this too closely, but I have noticed that every time I see a Quine question, it has negative votes or is closed or both.

Is there anything interesting left to do with Quines? Or are all these questions coincidently falling short in other respects?

Comment: I wrote 2 quine questions, both having a positive vote, but nobody posted a valid answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## No, quines are not played-out

I believe there will *always* be new ways of formulating good challenges, and some of those yet to be made good challenges will involve quines. Saying "we've asked every quine problem there could ever be" is like saying we've thought of every math problem there could ever be.

If you only mean that the *current* state of quine challenges is suffering, that may well be. It is difficult to think of totally fresh ideas involving quines which are somewhat static in nature (and prone to loophole gray areas). But I wouldn't discount the topic in the grand scheme of things.

**Additional note:** It seems likely that [this recent badly received question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/49332/26997) played a part in your quine skepticism. I think the [underhanded](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/underhanded) part was its real downfall. Writing good underhanded challenges is arguably much more difficult than writing good quine challenges, since their nature is *much* more subjective and even more prone to loophole gray areas.

Comment: That's a very good pragmatic/optimistic perspective, and I'm inclined to accept it.

Comment: If @Calvin's Hobbies *says* there are more quine questions, then there *are* more quine questions ;-)